# find whether a library is installed using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, deb

I'm complete noobs in shell script what i want is shell script that determine a list of library/package currently installed if not install them without user permission

What I want is to determine the library/package is currently installed or not in system

I'm aware of **aptitude search** command but I looking for a better solution

e.g I have define(in shell script) check for readline library/package now how can I from inside the shell script (I want to create) know that readline package is currently installed or not.

Any idea or suggestion would certainly help

Comment: What package manager? What shell? What language? You need to provide details in order to receive help.

Comment: Define "library/package".  This covers a lot of territory.  Also, installing things without user interaction requires root access.

Comment: Technically installing things the normal distribution way, ie, system wide would require root access.  Grabbing a private copy from somewhere and storing it under the user's directory for use by a single user/application would not, though I'd personally be unhappy if I wasn't asked to confirm any fetches of remotely sourced binaries.  But for something common like readline, I'd think it **much** better to trigger the distribution's packager to supply it.

Comment: @Blender sorry linux(ubuntu) bash shell hope this help

Comment: @JimGarrison library/package will be any thing but will be relevant to ruby language i.e compiling dependency for ruby e.g readline or openssl etc

Comment: "install them without user permission" -- unlikely, unless you're already root.

Comment: @glennjackman that I can manage I have already written script for that for manage permission issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What I want is to determine the library/package is currently installed or not in system

`dpkg -s` does not require root permission, and will display package status details.

Example shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh

for P; do
    dpkg -s "$P" >/dev/null 2>&1 && {
        echo "$P is installed."
    } || {
        echo "$P is not installed."
    }
done
```

Usage is:

`script.sh package1 package2 .... packageN`

Comment: **Be careful**: If `dpkg -s` returns `0`, it doesn't necessarily mean that the package is **fully/correctly** installed. `dpkg -s` also returns `0` if the package is in `half-configured` or in `config-files` state (and I guess also in `half-installed`, but I didn't check that). See [the man page of `dpkg`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/dpkg.1.html) for further "incomplete" states.

Answer (score 2):

For simply doing the test, it would seem that you could grep the output of a command such as ldconfig -p for your library of interest.

Or you could supply a tiny test program linked against the desired library, try running it, and test for non-failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set up a dependency check, the proper solution is to create a dummy package which `Depends:` on the packages you need to have installed.  There is a tool called [equivs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/equivs) which somewhat helps with this.  (However, it has been criticized as being "over-engineered"; certainly, if you are familiar with the format of Debian packages, you might not need a separate tool if your requirements are this simple.)  Then you just install this package and it will pull in the packages which are specified as dependencies.

You still have to know that the library which provides `libreadline.so` is `libreadline5-dev`.  [Debian package search](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libreadline.so) can help find the package names you need to put in `Depends:`

Comment: `apt-file` is another good way to search for "what (available) package contains a file name X".

Comment: @thepaul thanks I'm aware of apt-file but that not  the requirement over here

Answer (score -1):

You can probably do what you want with [`dpkg`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg)